# compare a dataframe column with another dataframe column for string match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

Currently I am having two dataset one with 100,000 rows and another with 25000 rows, I am comparing a column from second dataset to be contained in the column of first dataset.

So I'm using list comprehension with string.findall operation,I could acheive the results but the problem is Efficiency. It takes around 12 minutes to compute the operation. I have used Dask for the computation it drastically reduced the time but converting back to pandas dataframe takes the 12 minute benefit.

Tried three ways:

1.

```
df['first_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if any(word in str(x.description) 
                            for word in first_name_list) else False, axis=1)
```

2. ```
   df1 = list of items from the column to be comapred in second dataset

   (df['description'].str.lower()).str.findall(r'\b({})\b'.format(df1))
   ```

3. `Dask` as mentioned before.

All takes the same time of 12+ minutes

Detailed Info:

I wanted to populate the column with matched results for example:
df1:
|error id |description                                 |
|---------|--------------------------------------------|
|23e13e   |the world isnt small AAAA but yes BBBB      |
|12w12q   |the time isnt enough CCCC AAAA              |

df2:
|id |first_name |
|---|-----|
|1  |AAAA |
|2  |BBBB |
|3  |CCCC |
Now I should insert a new column in df1 for retreiving the name
df1:
|error_id| description                           |First_name|
|--------|---------------------------------------|----------|
|23e13e  |the world isnt small AAAA but yes BBBB |AAAA,BBBB |
|12w12q  |the time isnt enough CCCC AAAA         |CCCC,AAAA |

Comment: How about `df['first_name'] = df['description'].str.match('|'.join(first_name_list))`?

Comment: please share a couple of rows of each dataframe and or the list

Answer (score 3):

The essence of this whole problem is that you are trying to solve it iteratively, that is, one line at a time. The reason we all love pandas so much is because it does things all at once. Vectorized, some say.

Import pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
```

First Dataframe

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    ['some', 'group', 'of', 'strings', 'with', 'words', 'like', 'cat', 'dog'], columns=['Words']
)
```

Second Dataframe

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    ['cat', 'fish', 'dog', 'goat', 'chicken'], columns=['Animals']
)
```

df1

```
         Words
    0     some
    1    group
    2       of
    3  strings
    4     with
    5    words
    6     like
    7      cat
    8      dog
```

df2

```
    
       Animals
    0      cat
    1     fish
    2      dog
    3     goat
    4  chicken
```

Discovering if it is True or False that an item from df1['Words'] column is somewhere within df2['Aniamls'] column

```py
words_in_animals_condition = df1['Words'].isin(df2['Animals'])
print(words_in_animals_condition)
```

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: Words, dtype: bool
```

Discovering WHICH words from df1['Words'] are in column df2['Animals']

```py
words_in_animals = df1.loc[words_in_animals_condition]
print(words_in_animals)
```

```
  Words
7   cat
8   dog
```

Comment: Thanks @Nesha25 but this wasnt I expected, I have added detail in the question.